# Growth of a modified Zeta function appearing in the non-holomorphic Siegel Eisenstein series

Tags: eisenstein-series, siegel-modular-forms

In a paper (Eisenstein series for Siegel modular groups, https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01459520.pdf) Mizumoto obtains an explicit Fourier expansion for the non-holomorphic Siegel Eisenstein series 
$E_k^{(m)}(Z,s)$. In theorem (1.8), one of the "constant terms" appearing contains the function $\zeta_v^{(m)}(g,s)$ which he defines in formula (1.7).

I am interested only in one particular case, namely
$$\zeta_1^{(2)}(g,s)=\sum_{(c,d)\in\mathbb{Z}^2/\pm1}^{(c,d)=1}\left((c\ d)g\binom{c}{d}\right)^{-s}$$
where $g$ is a symmetric positive definite real matrix of size $2\times 2$ and $s\in\mathbb{C}$.

> Can we deduce anything that looks like $\zeta_1^{(2)}(g,s)\le c \det(g)^\alpha$ for some constants $c,\alpha$ **not** depending on $g$?

It's easy to see that we can replace the sum defining $\zeta_1^{(2)}$ by removing the coprimality condition (which amounts to introducing a factor of Riemann $\zeta(s)$) and then we can integrate instead of summing, so that in the end
$$\zeta_1^{(2)}(g,s)\ll\int_{x^2+y^2\ge 1}\left((x\ y)g\binom{x}{y}\right)^{-s}dx dy$$
and now we diagonalize $g=P^t\ \mbox{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2) P$ where $0<\lambda_1\le\lambda_2$ and $P$ is an orthogonal matrix, so after replacing and changing variables (it's just a rotation by $P$)
$$\zeta_1^{(2)}(g,s)\ll\int_{x^2+y^2\ge 1}\left(\lambda_1 x^2+\lambda_2 y^2\right)^{-s}dx dy$$
After factoring out $\lambda_2$, assuming $s$ is large enough so that the integral converges, we see that $\zeta_1^{(2)}(g,s)\ll\lambda_2^{-s}$. This is close to what I am expecting, but not quite: I really need something in terms of $\det(g)=\lambda_1\lambda_2$ and not just $\lambda_2$.

Comment: Why are you factoring out $\lambda_2$?  Convert the last integral to polar coordinates; it is easily computed and the natural bound is $\pi (\lambda_1+\lambda_2)^{-s}/(s-1)$.

Comment: @stopple still, that gives me the trace and I need the determinant. Given that Y is the imaginary part of a Z in the fundamental Siegel domain for $Sp_4$, maybe there is a nice relation between the two?

Comment: That's the question you should be asking, because the bound naturally comes out in terms of trace.

Comment: @Stopple oh well I can use the inequality for arithmetic and geometric mean and (assuming for instance real $s>0$) $(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)^{-s}\ll (\lambda_1\lambda_2)^{-s/2}$ which seems promising.

Comment: @Stopple how do you actually compute the last integral? I have tried converting to polar coordinates and I am stuck at $\int (A\cos x+B)^{-s}dx$ for some numbers $A,B$...

Comment: My claim above is wrong, but the integral can be done in polar coordinates $r,\theta$.   Define $\rho$, $\phi$, $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ by $\lambda_1=\mu_1^2$, $\lambda_2=\mu_2^2$, $\{\mu_1,\mu_2\}=\{\rho\cos(\phi),\rho\sin(\phi)$.  The $\rho$ contribution factors out, and the integral over $r$ is elementary.  Mathematica can do the integral over $\theta$, it is a complicated expression of Gamma and Hypergeometric function expressions in $\phi$ and $s$.